# How to sort by data in an object? (as3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an object consisting of numerical data like this:

```
var records:Object = {};

records["nh"] = { medinc:66303};
records["ct"] = { medinc:65958};
records["nj"] = { medinc:65173};
records["md"] = { medinc:64596};
```

etc...

I am wondering how I can sort the object numerically by the values in "medinc"?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var records:Object = {};
var arr:Array = [
                    records["nh"] = { medinc:66303},
                    records["ct"] = { medinc:65958},
                    records["nj"] = { medinc:65173},
                    records["md"] = { medinc:64596},
                    records["kk"] = { medinc:61321} 
                ];

arr.sortOn("medinc", Array.NUMERIC);

for each (var value:* in arr){
    trace(value.medinc);
}
```

Object is an associative array, because of the sort, for it is pointless, not access indexed. Instead, put it in an array(Indexed Arrays). the sort meaning.

and refer a following documentation.

[Assoociative Arrays (a.k.a Object)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7eea.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7edb)

[Indexed Arrays (a.k.a Array)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ee5.html)

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, I needed to sort an `array` by 2 indexes. A `score` *(descending)* and, if the `scores` were equal, order by `id` *(ascending)*.

Here is how its done:

```
players.sortOn(
    ["score", "id"],
    [Array.DESCENDING | Array.NUMERIC, Array.NUMERIC]
);
```

Pipe `|` to combine multiple options, like `DESCENDING | NUMERIC`.